# How can I change something to have a different name in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

Question is I have a  model named empaccrl and the table is called accrl. In accrl I have a column named accrual_code the data from this column is either PERSDAY3 or VACATION1... How can I change the name of them to Personal and Vacation with out having to change the data in my db... This is what I have so far but, it seems to not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is my empaccrl model

```
class Empaccrl < ActiveRecord::Base

  establish_connection :dev

  self.table_name = 'accrl'

  belongs_to :entry


  def accrual_code
    if @accrual_code == "PERSDAY3"
      accrual_code = 'Personal'
  end
  if @accrual_code == "VACATION1"
      accrual_code = 'Vacation'
  end
end
```

This is my view

```
  %table.table.table-bordered.trace-table
    %tr
    -@empaccrl.each do |ea|
      %tr
        %td.trace-table.bordered.trace-table{:style => 'width:10%;'}= ea.accrual_code
```

I also tried this... and it didn't work..

```
     %table.table.table-bordered.trace-table
    %tr
    -@empaccrl.each do |ea|
    - if ea.accrual_code = "PERSDAY3"
      %tr
        %td.trace-table.bordered.trace-table{:style => 'width:10%;'}= ea.accrual_code = "Personal"
    - else
      %tr
        %td.trace-table.bordered.trace-table{:style => 'width:10%;'}= ea.accrual_code = "Vacation"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close! The problem is that the instance variable `@accrual_code` doesn't have a value. Rails doesn't set instance variables for attributes. You can instead access the value with `self[attribute_name]`:

```
def accrual_code
  case self[:accrual_code]
    when "PERSDAY3" then "Personal"
    when "VACATION1" then "Vacation"
    else self[:accrual_code]
  end
end
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept my answer if you're able.